# Quarkus REST client: The element has invalid child element when sending XML

Tags: xml, quarkus, microprofile, quarkus-rest-client

It is not possible for me to use the Quarkus Rest client (org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client), because it modifies the XML under the hood and makes it invalid. In detail:

I have some XML which looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "OrderRequest")

public class OrderRequest {   

    @XmlElement(name="Company", defaultValue = "My Company")
    private String company = "My Company";

    @XmlElement(name = "Order")
    private OrderType order;
}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OrderType", propOrder = {
    "GetContracts"
})
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OrderType {

    @XmlElement(name = "GetContracts")
    protected GetContractsType getContracts;
}
```

which should build an XML in the end that looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OrderRequest>
  <Company>My Company</Company>
  <Order>
    <GetContracts>
      <!-- more tags -->
    </GetContracts>
  </Order>
</OrderRequest>
```

Quarkus rest client definition:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@RegisterProviders({
        @RegisterProvider(ResponseExceptionHandler.class),
        @RegisterProvider(RequestFilter.class),
        @RegisterProvider(ResponseFilter.class)
})

@RegisterClientHeaders(ApiHeaderHandler.class)
// @RegisterRestClient
@RestClient
public interface ApiService {

    @POST
    @Path("/Order")
    Object orderRequest(OrderRequest orderRequest);

}
```

invocation....

```
   ApiService apiService = org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
              .baseUri(URI.create(url))
              .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .build(ApiService.class);
   apiService.orderRequest(orderRequest); //build via Java with the classes above
```

The invocation works, because I get a response from the target api which says *XML invalid: The element 'Order' has invalid child element 'getContracts'*.

This means that anywhere under the hood this rest client makes probably some strange reflection thing, because it modifies the XML types itself! First of all, I thought it takes the getter method, so I changed getContracts to GetContracts, but no effect. Then I thought that "Get" confuses the framework, so it could lead to some strange reflection behaviour, so I renamed it to "FooContracts" to narrow the problem down. But then, the error messages says *XML invalid: The element 'Order' has invalid child element 'fooContracts'*, so it is no a problem with "get", because it even makes "Foo" to lowercase!

I made some tests with Postman to match the responses and indeed, I get the same error in Postman when I send this XML with lowercase getContracts...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OrderRequest>
  <Company>My Company</Company>
  <Order>
    <getContracts>
      <!-- more tags -->
    </getContracts>
  </Order>
</OrderRequest>
```

*XML invalid: The element 'Order' has invalid child element 'getContracts'*.

So it is clear, this Quarkus Rest client or something else under the hood damages the XML by making elements lowercase. Any ideas what I can do now?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Have you verified that within the class `OrderType`, you are using the correct `@XmlElement`-Annotation?

Comment: If you are in deed using the correct `@XmlElement`, please provide a [MRE] (e.g. a git repository).